# Push faded/withdrawn candidates to the bottom of the page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, election

There seems to be a lot of candidate attrition right at the beginning of the primary voting (over 10% in a few hours time).  The faded text is distracting in an already long page.

If we have to have them on the page, can we at least sort them to the bottom of the page?

Comment: And replace their nomination text with "withdrawn"...

Comment: Good idea! agreed!

Comment: This is not [status-completed], since the withdrawn nominations, even reduced in size, still clutter the page by appearing in between other candidates. [Here is how it looks on Math right now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hC6c5.png).

Answer (score 10):

Also, put a thick `<hr/>` and write a heading, "The following candidates have withdrawn their nominations." Then show all the withdrawn nominations there.

That would help in clearing up the page.

Answer (score 5):

After the next build we will suppress candidates who have withdrawn and show a much smaller version of their info.

Answer (score 4):

With a new election happening right now, can we please have this feature?

In my opinion not only should the post be pushed to the bottom, but also collapsed or maybe moved to an entirely different page altogether (eg: "Withdrawn nominations").

Since you can't vote for them, the posts only add clutter to an already cluttered page.