# Remove withdrawn candidates from the primary

Tags: feature-request, election, moderator-primaries

The [Stack Overflow moderator election primary  has begun](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2), and there were several candidates who were immediately withdrawn (didn't meet badge requirements perhaps?).

Whatever the reason, they all have position statements that are effectively just taking up space. They're completely unactionable.

Can nominations that have been withdrawn be removed?

Comment: This seems to be the next step of the [old (and completed) feature request for decreasing emphasis on withdrawn candidates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76435/push-faded-withdrawn-candidates-to-the-bottom-of-the-page).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think we can completely remove them, because doing so would conflict with an important part of the blurb in the election page's sidebar:

> The candidate vote scores are all public.

Since *all* votes cast to nominations are public, they arguably have to remain accessible somehow even if a nomination is withdrawn further down the line.

However, position statements in withdrawn nominations are indeed unactionable and do make up the bulk of the post. I second you on that point, and would suggest we only hide the position statement but keep the candidate's user card and vote count visible, albeit dimmed in the usual way.

Something like:

[image]

**EDIT:** [Another candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265570/offbysome) has chosen to delete his position statement himself before withdrawing, which achieves the same effect.

Comment: Ha yep it was clear I had no chance so I withdrew to not take up any more space on the crowded page.

Comment: Under certain circumstances I believe "rogue votes" are owned by Community, so I'm not sure there'd be any technical difficulty in doing so here. Plus, it need not affect the votes at all, simply don't show the non-candidates, unless I'm missing something.