# Weird candidate block on primary election tab

Tags: bug, design, election

There is weird candidate information block on the [current moderator election on ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/4?tab=primary):

> [image: gray candidate]

Whole block is grayed, no information, no up/down-vote button, score is missaligned etc ...

What's going on here? If that candidate is removed from election, can we show more obvious information in that block? Or even do not show that candidate at all.

Comment: The layout would suggest that this entry was deleted. The links still work in the card, and there is nothing obvious on the user profile that would disqualify them from running as far as I can tell.

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112123/remove-withdrawn-candidates-from-the-primary?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I guess this is the intended behavior, but I think it needs to be changed, for the sake of accessibility and sanity. Everything is too greyed out so a normal person can’t even see what that is. And then, for the people who can see that there’s text there (which seems to say “history” in English elections), it’s not making it obvious enough what this ghost block is. I didn’t think that was a link: it looks like the candidate just had that one word as their nomination.